# Looping sound in SoundEffect class Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I am developing a game, and need to add background music for that. I tried `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio` namespace's `SoundEffect` class.

Initially I used

```
SoundEffectInstance Sound = 
     SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/background.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream).CreateInstance();
Sound.IsLooped = true;
Sound.Play();
```

And it was not working. Then I tried

```
SoundEffect sound;
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(
            new Uri("Assets/background.wav", UriKind.Relative));
sound= SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
sound.Play();
```

And its working. But Cant loop the music. 
Can anyone please describe me the differences and suggest a way to loop the music please.

Edit : I wanna call this is `public MainPage() { }

Update : I made it work by adding this in delegates as below

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  startBackgroundMusic();
}

private void startBackgroundMusic()
{
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
  {
    StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(
      new Uri("Assets/background.wav", UriKind.Relative));
    backgroundMusic = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);
    SoundEffectInstance instance = backgroundMusic.CreateInstance();
    instance.IsLooped = true;
    instance.Play();

  });
}
```

Now I have another problem that, the audio file duration is 2mins but the above code plays the music only for 30 seconds. How to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The SoundEffect class does indeed not support looping. Therefore you need the `SoundEffectInstance` class. You can create an instance of this class based on your already created SoundEffect-instance:

```
//What you already had:
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/background.wav", UriKind.Relative));
SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(info.Stream);

//Here's the magic:
SoundEffectInstance instance = sound.CreateInstance();
instance.IsLooped = true;
instance.Play();
```

More reading (MSDN)

- [**Playing a Sound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195053.aspx)
- [**Looping a Sound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx)
- [**SoundEffect class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx)
- [**SoundEffectInstance class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx)

Comment: Could you update your question with your MainPage-event? What is not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Its not returning errors, and also not playing the sound. The same code works for a button click event.

Comment: Best is to run the code when the page is Loading/Loaded and not to run it in the constructor of the MainPage. But please, show your MainPage-code (add it to your question).

Comment: Its working after I tried to put it in a delegate. But the audio file duration is 2 mins and for the below code, the audio file plays only for less then 30 seconds.

code is gisted https://gist.github.com/IshamMohamed/9252224 here

Comment: And can you try the same code in the Loaded event of the page (without the delegate)? Does that work?