# Looping music seamlessly with XNA _AND_ while app is in the background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, visual-studio-2013

1. I can loop music seamlessly by using XNA ([instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070480/looping-sound-in-soundeffect-class-windows-phone-8)).
2. I can also play music while app is in the background ([following instructions here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)).

Is there a way that I can combine them together? I would like the music to loop seamlessly AND while being able to play in the background? Following the instructions in #2, the music loops but there is a nasty gap between plays. I'd like them to be seamless, that's why I tried #1. Problem is it stops whenever the power, home, or back buttons are pressed. Any advice for a C# newbie?

Thanks!

Comment: about gaps between plays, maybe your song is not trimmed so it have some extra "silence" at end?

Comment: The music plays seamlessly when I use XNA. I just need to be able to keep it playing when the device enters sleep mode, or if the app enters the background.

Comment: I think normal behaviour is that when i put application in background, application goes to pause mode. because i wanted to check something else (skype call, check email or some video) and i don't want to be interrupted by some background music. imho.

Comment: I'm trying to build a music app similar to the native Windows Phone music app. The user can play music, then go back to the start screen to do other stuff like check emails, browse the web, and respond to email. All this should be done with the music playing in the background, looping seamlessly. Of course playback will stop once a Skype call is started, or video is played, but i just need to be able to: 1.) ensure gapless looping; and 2.) background playback. I can do both separately, but I'm at wit's end trying to join these two features together... :)

Comment: I believe this is unrelated to XNA. I think you need to edit some project settings to allow the App to run in the background. Maybe also allow it to play music in the background.